# Wie bezeichnet man die Jahrzehnte zwischen 2000 und 2020?

Tags: numbers, time

Für das letzte Jahrhundert sind Bezeichnungen wie die ***"50er-Jahre"*** oder ***"in den Achtzigerjahren"*** für die Jahre zwischen 1950-1959, bzw. 1980-1989 üblich.

Gibt es für die Dekaden zwischen 2000 und 2010 und zwischen 2010 und 2020 ähnlich kurze und prägnante Bezeichnungen? Mir fallen nur lange und umständliche Formulierungen ein:

> "*in den Jahren 2000 bis 2010*"
>   "*im ersten Jahrzehnt unseres Jahrtausends"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt keine allgemeine Übereinkunft, wie die Jahre 2000 bis 2009 umgangssprachlich bezeichnet werden sollen. Die am häufigsten verwendeten Namen sind die "2000er (Jahre)" und die "Nullerjahre".

Für die Jahre 2010 bis 2019 hört man häufig die "Zehnerjahre".

Comment: In der täglichen Sprache habe ich beides noch nie gehört. Ich selbst würde es wahrscheinlich auch irgendwie anders und potentiell jedes Mal unterschiedlich formulieren.

Comment: Habe insb. Nullerjahre schon mehrfach gehört, aber richtig fest sind die Begriffe nicht...

Answer (score 6):

Die Frage eignet sich, was den Gebrauch in der Schriftsprache betrifft, prima als Futter für Googles NGram-Viewer (leider gibt es wohl keine brauchbare Suchanfrage für Texte mit „das erste Jahrzehnt“ oder ähnliches, wobei sich die Angabe zB nur auf das 20. Jahrhundert beziehen soll - auch „Zwanziger Jahre“ muss sich nicht zwingend auf den entsprechenden Zeitraum im 20. Jhd. beziehen):

- [1910-1919](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1910er%20Jahre,Zehnerjahre&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

  [image: 1910]
- [1920-1929](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1920er%20Jahre,%20Zwanzigerjahre,Zwanziger%20jahre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

  [image: 1920]
- [1930-1939](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1930er%20Jahre,Drei%C3%9Figerjahre,Drei%C3%9Figer%20jahre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

  [image: 1930]
- [2000-2009](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=2000er%20Jahre,Nullerjahre&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

  [image: 2000]

Jedenfalls in der Schriftsprache scheint also die Schreibung mit der Jahreszahl üblicher (geworden) zu sein als der ausgeschriebene Begriff. Interessant aber, dass das eine moderne Entwicklung zu sein scheint (höhere Präzision der kompletten Jahreszahl? verändertes Stilempfinden?). Das sagt natürlich noch nichts darüber aus, wie das gelesen werden würde; ich nehme an, umgangssprachlich „neunzehnzwanziger Jahre“, korrekt eher "neunzehnhundertzwanziger Jahre". Oder man lässt Wort und Schrift divergieren und liest „Zwanzigerjahre“, wo „1920er Jahre“ steht.

Zur eigentlichen Frage: für „Nullerjahre“ und „Zehnerjahre“ zeigt der ngram-Viewer keinen einzigen Treffer, eine Google-Books-Suche aber deren 181 (für „Nullerjahre“). Insgesamt liefert Google für „Nullerjahre“ etwa 308.000 Treffer. Das scheint mir [splattners Einschätzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/wie-bezeichnet-man-die-jahrzehnte-zwischen-2000-und-2020/2730#2730) prima zu bestätigen, dass es sich hierbei eher um Umgangssprache handelt.

Comment: +1 Kleine Ergänzung: Bei Wikipedia steht, dass "Nuller Jahre" im Rahmen der Jahrzehntrückblicke 2009 in Mode kamen. Ngram geht meines Wissens nur bis 2008.

Comment: @splattne: stimmt, gut beobachtet!

Comment: Was sagt man eigentlich zu 1900-1920? Das dürfte ein ähnliches Problem sein.

Comment: @Takkat: Oh weh - ich glaube, das ist noch schwieriger, weil es hier bereits keine ohne weiteres benennbare Gemeinsamkeit gibt. Für „zehn Jahre“ gibt es wenigstens noch „Dekade“, „Jahrzehnt“ oder „Dezennium“; die Jahre gehören ja auch zur „selben Gruppe“ im Zehnersystem. Für „20 Jahre“ liest man ganz vereinzelt „Vintennium“. Wo das [Vigesimalsystem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimalsystem) gebräuchlich ist, könnte es wieder anders aussehen...

Comment: Die 20er-Jahre sind, solange es noch nicht 2020 ist, die 1920er Jahre, weil man kaum Anlass hat von den 2020er Jahren zu sprechen, wie man auch kaum Anlass hat von den 1820er Jahren zu sprechen.